# Primefaces BarChart custom labels for bars

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jqplot

I wanted to show custom labels above bars in BarChart, so that instead of exact bar values there would be my custom text. I tried setting label for ChartSerie in combination with ShowPointLabels for BarChartModel but that did not work.

I thought about different method of using extender for my bar chart, so that it would be something like this (example taken from [here](http://www.jqplot.com/examples/point-labels.php), "Bar Chart with Point Labels"):

```
function barExt() {
    this.cfg.series=[
                {pointLabels:{
                    show:true,
                    labels: ['lbl1', 'lbl2, 'lbl3']
                }
             }];
}
```

But instead of working labels for single serie (just first one is shown, no other dataset in chart) I get error: TypeError: D[w] is undefined

I also tried copying script from above link and adding pointLabel and it worked.

Is there any way to achieve what I want by using bar chart from Primefaces or there's just path of manual chart creation?

I'm using Primefaces 6.0, Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/8.5.3 (7.0.1), JDK 1.7.0_80-b15, Mojarra 2.2.6.

Comment: You can do this on your Java Managed Bean where you define your chart. Setting the label for each series. Check out the documentation http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/bar.xhtml click on the "Documentation" link you will see how to do it in the first page it opens.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Label for series shows text under whole series (in linked showcase it is "2004", "2005" etc.) I'd like to show text over each bar - when you hoover mouse over single bar it shows serie index and value for that bar: this is what I'd like to change and show without need to hoover mouse.